# MSBuild - Copy file to output directory if the file isn't in the output directory

Tags: msbuild, nuget, target

I have a nuget with a .targets file that tells the consuming project to copy all files within a "Dependencies" folder to the output directory.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Files Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)/../contentFiles/Dependencies/*.*" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="CopyDependencies" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(Files)" 
          DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)" />
  </Target>
```

This nuget is consumed by two projects: `Project A` and `Project B`. For this question, let's say we have a `System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll` that is one of the dependencies within this nuget. The output directory of Project A does not already have `System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll`, so it gets copied to the output directory when the project is built. Project B however already contains `System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll` in the output directory. This causes a runtime issue at startup since the targets file is trying to overwrite the existing DLL of the same name with the `System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll` file from within the nuget (which is a dependency of other files within the output directory).

So, how can I adjust my .targets file to only copy in files that do not already exist within the output directory **based on name**, and **not size or date modified**?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways but probably the most succinct change to your example code would be the following:

```xml
    <ItemGroup>
        <Files Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)/../contentFiles/Dependencies/*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="CopyDependencies" AfterTargets="Build">
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(Files)" DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)" Condition="!Exists('$(TargetDir)/%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
    </Target>
```

The change is adding a `Condition` on the `Copy` that is using the metadata of the `@(Files)` collection to test that the file does not exist in `$(TargetDir)`.

Because of the use of metadata, the `Copy` is a [task batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-batching?view=vs-2022#task-batching). Essentially the `@(Files)` collection is divided into batches by `%(Filename)%(Extension)` and there is a separate `Copy` task invoked for each batch.

If there is a large number of files in the `Dependencies` folder, the following variant may provide better performance.

```xml
    <ItemGroup>
        <Files Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)/../contentFiles/Dependencies/*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="CopyDependencies" AfterTargets="Build">
        <ItemGroup>
            <FilesToCopy Include="@(Files)" Condition="!Exists('$(TargetDir)/%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
        </ItemGroup>

        <Copy SourceFiles="@(FilesToCopy)" DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)" />
    </Target>
```

The task batching is moved to the definition of a new `ItemGroup` collection and the `Copy` task is invoked once for the set of files. The potential performance improvement is that the implementation of the `Copy` task tries to parallelize copies, which it can't do when invoked per file.